# How a Custom Metadata Type's field value can be referred in Lightning Component?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, url, custom-metadata

I have an URL that was saved in a Text(255) field of the **Custom Metadata Type**. I wanted to refer this Url on to the Lightning component, to make my custom onClick() to redirect to this Url. How can I pass this URL to `window.location.href`?

Do I need to query the field in an Apex Controller class using:

`Select Id, UrlField from MyPortal_Configuration_Setting__mdt`

If yes, how can implement in Component's JS controller?
If no, what is the valid workaround for referring URL from Custom Metadata type? Can someone take a look at this please?

Answer (score 2):

To redirect to an url, if you're in Lightning Experience you should make use of the
[force:navigateToURL](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_force_navigateToURL.htm) event.

To get the Custom Metadata Type, I'm afraid you'll have to query the server via an Apex Controller, yes. I tried to use [Lightning Data Service](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.208.0.lightning.meta/lightning/data_service.htm), but unfortunately it doesn't work with Custom Metadata. But I would definitely keep an eye on it as it would make sense to support Custom Metadata Types in LDS in the future.

Comment: I was able to query this way: 
      `@AuraEnabled
       public static My_Portal_Configuration_Setting__mdt getLogoutUrl() {
           List<My_Portal_Configuration_Setting__mdt> logoutUrl = 
            [Select Id, Logout_URL__c from 
          My_Portal_Configuration_Setting__mdt LIMIT 1];   
        return logoutUrl[0];  
    }`.
On JS I tried to implement this: But received **undefined**:
`var logUrl = component.get("c.getLogoutUrl");
             console.log('Url: ' +logUrl);`
Could you please help me out in implementing in JS?

Comment: Have you tried returning just a String ?

Comment: Actually I was getting this in console 
`Url: [object Object]`.

Comment: Can you use console.log('Url: ', logUrl); ? "," instead of "+", and see what's inside the object.

Comment: After changing the return value to String and with above console log, I have got this: `J {va: SI, Ji: null, Ng: Object, background: false, H: a…}`

Comment: In your Apex Class, if you System.debug logoutUrl[0].Logout_URL__c, is it ok ? What about returning just that information as it's the only one you need ? Easier and lightweight.

Comment: I got the same return from Apex controller class: `logoutUrl[0].Logout_URL__c`, which is returning right URL when I run via **Open Execute Anonymous Window**. Am I missing something?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58959/discussion-between-fabien-taillon-and-arnold-jr).